# How can I get a specific value by index from a custom Model in QML?

Tags: qt, qml, qtquick2

I'm trying to get the name from a specific user based on an **index** from the **UserModel** (*which is a list model according to the wiki*).

When I attempt to print out the name using `console.log("username: {" + userModel.get(userList.currentSelected).name+ "}")`, I get the following error:

> Main.qml:56: TypeError: Type error

*SDDM repository*: https://github.com/sddm/sddm/wiki/Theming

I tried `userModel.get(0)`, `userModel.at(0)`, `userModel[0]`  but none of those have worked for me.

###### Main.qml

```
import QtQuick 2.15
import SddmComponents 2.0

Item {
    id: root
    focus: true
    Keys.onPressed: (event)=> {
        console.log("Object entries:" + Object.entries(userModel));
        console.log(userModel.itemData(userModel.index(0, 0)));
        console.log("username: {" + userModel.get(0).name+ "}")
    }
}
```

**Edit**: here is the output of `object.entries`:

> <sub>[[objectName,],[lastIndex,0],[lastUser,],[count,4],[disableAvatarsThreshold,7],[containsAllUsers,true],[objectNameChanged,function() { [native code] }],[dataChanged,function() { [native code] }],[headerDataChanged,function() { [native code] }],[layoutChanged,function() { [native code] }],[layoutAboutToBeChanged,function() { [native code] }],[rowsAboutToBeInserted,function() { [native code] }],[rowsInserted,function() { [native code] }],[rowsAboutToBeRemoved,function() { [native code] }],[rowsRemoved,function() { [native code] }],[columnsAboutToBeInserted,function() { [native code] }],[columnsInserted,function() { [native code] }],[columnsAboutToBeRemoved,function() { [native code] }],[columnsRemoved,function() { [native code] }],[modelAboutToBeReset,function() { [native code] }],[modelReset,function() { [native code] }],[rowsAboutToBeMoved,function() { [native code] }],[rowsMoved,function() { [native code] }],[columnsAboutToBeMoved,function() { [native code] }],[columnsMoved,function() { [native code] }],[submit,function() { [native code] }],[revert,function() { [native code] }],[resetInternalData,function() { [native code] }],[hasIndex,function() { [native code] }],[index,function() { [native code] }],[parent,function() { [native code] }],[sibling,function() { [native code] }],[rowCount,function() { [native code] }],[columnCount,function() { [native code] }],[hasChildren,function() { [native code] }],[data,func
> tion() { [native code] }],[setData,function() { [native code] }],[headerData,function() { [native code] }],[fetchMore,function() { [native code] }],[canFetchMore,function() { [native code] }],[flags,function() { [native code] }],[match,function() { [native code] }]]</sub>

Comment: According to [UserModel.h](https://github.com/sddm/sddm/blob/501129294be1487f753482c29949fc1c19ef340e/src/greeter/UserModel.h#L30) in its *GitHub repository*, **UserModel** is inherited from [**QAbstractListModel**](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qabstractitemmodel.html#itemData), which means you can use the **itemData** or **data** function to retrieve data at a specific index, like `userModel.itemData(userModel.index(0, 0))`. Also remember that the second parameter of the **index** function is the column index, which should be set to 0.

Comment: @smr I tried it and still got the same error

Comment: Try checking if **userModel** is not undefined. Print the **userModel** and its type. Additionally, print the properties of **userModel** using `Object.entries(userModel)` to see the list of functions it has. Also, include a minimal version of your code, not the entire file.

Comment: @smr Ok, I replaced it with a more simplified version of the code and added object.entries output. Printing out userModel itself shows `SDDM::UserModel(0x55b8c8426220)`. I also used `typeof userModel` and it came up with `object`.

Comment: @smr Seems like only certain functions from QAbstractItemModel work for some reason since `userModel.index()` and `userModel.count` were defined, but `userModel.itemData()` and `userModel.data()` weren't

Comment: I'm sorry for my mistake. It seems that the [**itemData**](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qabstractitemmodel.html#itemData) function is not invokable, and only the [**data**](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qabstractitemmodel.html#data) function is. You can call the data function, but you should pass the role raw value as its second parameter.

Comment: @smr Interesting, I tried `console.log(userModel.data(userModel.index(0,0), 0));` and I am still getting undefined. Not sure if this is reproducable

Comment: The first role starts after the [`Qt::UserRole`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qt.html#ItemDataRole-enum) value, which is 256 (ref: [*UserModel.h*](https://github.com/sddm/sddm/blob/501129294be1487f753482c29949fc1c19ef340e/src/greeter/UserModel.h#L40)). Therefore, the first role value would be 257.

Answer (score 0):

As @smr stated in the comments, `userModel.data(userModel.index(0,0), 257)` is the correct function.

[QAbstractItemModel::data](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qabstractitemmodel.html#data)
[Qt::ItemDataRole](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qt.html#ItemDataRole-enum)